# Why doesn't "-webkit-text-security: circle;" do anything?

Tags: html, css

This is my flawed code code:

```html
<tr> <td>Confirm Password:<span class="important_fill">*</span> </td> <td><input type="Password" name="password1" id="password1" size="30" style="-webkit-text-security: circle;" required/></td> <td style="color:Red" id="errorPassword1"></td> </tr>
```

This (putting `-webkit-text-security: circle;` in the `style` attribute of the input) worked on the login page, but when I tried on the registration page - suddenly it doesn't do anything. I want to change it to `circle` for aesthetics - anyone's got any idea?

Comment: What browser are you using it in?

Comment: Chrome, I am running both pages in Chrome - one works and the other one doesn't

Comment: This is a non-standard feature: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-text-security

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works for `input` not for type `password` change that in your HTML.

> Change  `input type="text"` from `input type="password"`.

```html
<tr>
  <td>Confirm Password:<span class="important_fill">*</span> </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" name="password1" id="password1" size="30" style="-webkit-text-security: circle;" required />
  </td>
  <td style="color:Red" id="errorPassword1"></td>
</tr>
```